# "hg tags --debug" for git

Tags: git, mercurial

I am migrating from Mercurial to Git.

Is there an equivalent command in git that do the same as the following Mercurial command:

```
hg tags --debug
```

Thanks

Comment: You are reducing the pool of persons that could answer to you to only people using git **and** mercurial and answering question in stackoverflow. That's not a good idea. You'd better explained what this command is doing... `git tag --list`?

Comment: What is it about the output of that --debug flag which you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg tags` list tags so I guess `hg tags --debug` is `hg tags --verbose`. In `git` it's roughly equivalent to

```
git tag --list -n1
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--nltnumgt

*Upd*. My guess about `--debug` was wrong. Let's fix it:

```
git tag -l --format='%(refname) -> %(*objectname)'
```

Comment: `--debug` turns on debugging output, but mostly this prints the full hash ID of the tags, instead of abbreviating them. It's not clear what the OP is doing *with* that full hash ID.